# change line color in middle of plot - plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Creating 12 subplots with plotly from a csv containing rows with 13 values. The last value indicates that the data in that row is estimated from this point until the status changes back in a later row.
Trying to make line graphs that plots a line, changes to red when the  status changes to 1, then back to original color when the status changes back to 0. Is this possible?

```
with lock:
    df = pd.read_csv(OCcsvFile, delimiter=',')

# plotly setup
plot_rows = 4
plot_cols = 3
# Create plot figure
fig = make_subplots(rows=plot_rows, cols=plot_cols, subplot_titles=("Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5",
                                                                    "Header6", "Header7", "Header8", "Header9", "Header10",
                                                                    "Header11", "Header12"))

# add traces
x = 1  # column counter
for i in range(1, plot_rows+1):
    for j in range(1, plot_cols+1):
        #print(str(i)+ ', ' + str(j))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.iloc[:, 0], y=df.iloc[:, x],
                                 name=df.columns[x],
                                 mode='lines'),
                      row=i,
                      col=j)
        x = x+1
```

Comment: Is status in the data? If the amount of data is small, can it be presented in text? Please post that and the current output as well.

Comment: I think @vestland's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760484/plotly-how-to-display-different-color-segments-on-a-line-chart-for-specified-th) will get you started on the right path. I'll work on integrating that solution into your specific question when I have the chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- taken approach of reshaping dataframe to be ready for **plotly express**
- have worked out starting dataframe from description, a sample would be better

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 10, [100, 12]), columns=[f"c{i+1}" for i in range(12)]
).assign(status=np.repeat(np.random.randint(0, 2, 20), 5))

# restructure dataframe for px
# 1. preserve status in index
# 2. make columns another level of index
# 3. make index columns and make column names meaningful
dfp = (
    df.set_index("status", append=True)
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "x", "level_2": "facet", 0: "value"})
)

# make sure missing values are present as NaN
dfp = dfp.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [dfp["x"].unique(), dfp["facet"].unique(), dfp["status"].unique()]
    )),
    left_on=["x", "facet", "status"],
    right_index=True,
    how="right"
)

# now it's a very simple plot
px.line(dfp, x="x", y="value", color="status", facet_col="facet", facet_col_wrap=4)
```

[image]

#### expected structure or df

- 13 columns, last column indicating the status

|  | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | c9 | c10 | c11 | c12 | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 1 |
| 11 | 4 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 8 | 1 |
| 12 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 9 | 7 | 1 |
| 13 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 14 | 4 | 9 | 9 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 | 9 | 6 | 2 | 9 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| 16 | 8 | 5 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 17 | 6 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 8 | 5 | 9 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 4 | 0 |
| 18 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 8 | 5 | 5 | 9 | 8 | 9 | 2 | 9 | 0 |
| 19 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 0 |

Comment: Wow!! It works. I don't fully understand your code at the moment, but I'll study it.  Thanks Greatly!

Comment: the reshaping of dataframe you can look at each intermediate step.  key is that **dfp** has a column for x,y, color and facet.  This needs to include NaN where nothing is to be plotted for combination of mentioned columns

Comment: facet plotting, now I know....so much to learn...