# Plotly: Is it possible to color specific portion of the line in line chart?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, linechart

Sample line chart

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")
fig.show()
```

[image]

I want to color the `values > 1.1` and `values<0.95` to a different color(ex: red)

[image]

Is it possible in plotly to color the specific portion of the line into a different color?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760484/plotly-how-to-display-different-color-segments-on-a-line-chart-for-specified-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can add a additional traces that are data points outside desired range
- note **pandas** techniques to ensure that all data points exist for additional trace (use of outer-join to get **NaN** for points within range)

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="GOOG").add_traces(
    px.line(
        df.loc[~df["GOOG"].between(0.95, 1.1)].merge(
            df, on="date", how="right", suffixes=("", "_r")
        ),
        x="date",
        y="GOOG",
    )
    .update_traces(line_color="red")
    .data
)

fig.show()
```

[image]